# Non-breaking content inside anchor tag which has fa icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

**How to make an anchor tag content non-breaking which has I tag inside it**

[anchor tag breaks likes in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRkHr.png)

But I want it without breaking. Like in this image
[Non-breaking anchor tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdFfK.png)

My HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

<a class="show-more-btn" href="javascript:void(0);">Read&nbsp;More&nbsp;<i style="font-size:15px;" class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

</body>
</html>
```

**is not working in this case.**

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `white-space: nowrap;` on the link?

Comment: Thanks, Temani Afif. By simply adding this thing it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `white-space: nowrap;` (see [white-space on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)) on your button:

```css
.show-more-btn i {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  max-width: 85px;
}

.show-more-btn {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div class="box">
<a class="show-more-btn" href="javascript:void(0);">Read&nbsp;More&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
```